# sample use cases for org.scribe.OAuthRequest.OAuthRequest(Verb verb, String url)

Tags: java, groovy, oauth, scribe

I am working on XeroAPI as a task given to me in my internship.  i am not familiar with OAuth and i'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to programming. right now i managed to do a simple OAuth using Ashley Schroder's tutorial on **Accessing Xero API for public applications using java** his code is working fine and i managed to understand how it works(a little but enough to understand how to use it)

Here comes my problem, it happens that i need to use other http requests like PUT and POST. i researched for days before coming here but to no avail. i would like to know if there's someone here who can show me a thing or two on other use cases for `Verb.PUT` and `Verb.POST`

Ashley Schroder's Page for scribe oauth implentation for Xero API public application: [Click Here](http://www.aschroder.com/2013/12/accessing-the-xero-api-for-public-applications-in-java/)

I would like to ask another question but i'll post it some other time.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a client library that already has support for PUT requests, etc. E.g. here are two popular ones:

https://github.com/connectifier/xero-java-client

https://github.com/rossjourdain/XeroAPI-PrivateApplication-Java